# Localhost not Loading - Continuous Spin in Title Tab

Tags: reactjs, localhost

OK, Localhost isn't loading for me. I just get a white page and a spinning loop around the logo in the tab. I am trying to connect on port 3000 as it suggested. Here's my App.js:

```
    import "./App.css";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {Login} from './pages/Login/Login';
import {Register} from './pages/Register/register';


function App() {
 return (
  
   <Router> <Register />
     <Switch>
       <Route path = '/' exact component = {Register} />
       <Route path ='/login' component = {Login} />
       <Route path ='/register' component= {Register} />
     </Switch>
   </Router>
 )
}


export default App;
```

The components I have so far:

```
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "../Register/register";
import "../Login/login.css";

export const Login = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Register} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>

      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <div className="left-container">
            <div>
              <img className="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="logo" />
            </div>
            <div className="boxes">
              <div className="box">
                <h2>Contact us</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="box">
                <h2>About us</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="box">
                <h2>Features</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="box">
                <Route to="/register" component={Register}>
                  <Link to="/register">
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                  </Link>
                </Route>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="right-container">
            <div class="register">
              <h1>Login</h1>
              <p className="sub-text">Please login to use Arappnid.</p>

              <form className="form-container">
                <div className="form-inner">
                  <div className="form-inner">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="textbox" className="form-input"></input>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-inner">
                    <div className="form-inner">
                      <label>Password</label>
                      <input type="password" className="form-input"></input>
                    </div>{" "}
                    <div>
                      <div className="button-container">
                        <button className="submit">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div></div>
              </form>
              <h1>Arappnid</h1>
              <div className="reg-benefits-cont">
                <p>
                  Ipsum eiusmod fugiat commodo sit. Nulla dolor deserunt et
                  officia nulla. Eiusmod sint do aliquip ullamco amet minim
                  velit ut mollit qui. Veniam tempor quis nostrud sit ut et
                  incididunt commodo ut dolor dolor non est excepteur. Velit id
                  sunt consequat sint deserunt magna Lorem nostrud in laborum
                  velit voluptate. Magna ut sit non eu nostrud. Amet magna qui
                  cupidatat quis culpa amet elit culpa.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

export default Login;

register.js:

```
    import {ReactComponent as Cockroach } from '../../images/svg/cockroach.svg';
import {ReactComponent as Spider } from '../../images/svg/tarantula.svg';
import {ReactComponent as Reminders} from '../../images/svg/reminders.svg';
import {ReactComponent as Gallery} from '../../images/svg/gallery.svg';
import { Switch, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '../Login/Login';

    export const Register = () =>{
        return(
        
         
          <header className="App-header">
            <div className="left-container">
            <Switch>
            <Route path = '/' exact component = {Register} />
            <Route path = '/register' component = {Register} />
            <Route path = 'login' component = {Login} />
    
          </Switch>
             <div>
                <img className="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="logo"/>
              </div>
              <div className="boxes">
              <div className="box">
                <h2>Contact us</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="box">
                <h2>About us</h2>
              </div>
              <div className="box">
                <h2>Features</h2>
              </div>
              
              <div className="box">
              
               <Link to ='/login'><h2>Login</h2></Link>
               
              </div>
              
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="right-container">
              <div class="register">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <p className="sub-text">
                  Please fill out the form below to register for Arappnid and use
                  the software.
                </p>
              
                  
                  <form className="form-container">
                 <div className="form-inner">
                    <label className="first-name">Name</label>
                    <input type='textbox' className="form-input"></input>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div className="form-inner">
                    <label>Surname</label>
                    <input type='textbox' className="form-input"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-inner">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type='textbox' className="form-input"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inner">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type='textbox' className="form-input"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-inner">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type='password' className="form-input"></input>
                    </div> <div>
                      <div className="button-container">
                      <button className="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div></div>
                    <div>
                    
                   </div>
                  </form>
                  <h1>Benefits of Registering</h1>
                  <div className="reg-benefits-cont">
                    <div className="benefits remove-margin">
                  
                      <Cockroach fill='rgb(117, 0, 128)'/>
                      <h4>Track Feeds</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="benefits">
                      <Spider className='pic' />
                      <h4>Track Unlimited Spiders</h4>
    
                    </div>
                    <div className="benefits">
                      <Reminders className='pic'/>
                      <h4>Receive Alerts</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="benefits">
                      <Gallery className="pic"/>
                      <h4> Personal Gallery</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </header>
         
        )
    }
    export default Register;
```

Any assistance would be great. Thanks in advance.

What I have tried:

```
I tried running it on a different port to no avail. I have also tried commenting out various parts of the code. I know it's messy.
```

Comment: Nistan, thanks for your fast respoinse. I don't know what that was doing there to be honest. I tried removing it and still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<Register />` component after the `<Router>`

```
   <Router> <Register /> //REMOVE THIS
     <Switch>
       <Route path = '/' exact component = {Register} />
       <Route path ='/login' component = {Login} />
       <Route path ='/register' component= {Register} />
     </Switch>
   </Router>
```